# View a changeset using mercurial

Tags: mercurial

How do I view a changeset of a mercurial repository.
I want to get the same output I get with

```
git show <commit>
```

How do I do this with hg?

Answer (score 1):

The git `show` command for commits shows log message and diff. The equivalent Mercurial command could be:

```
hg log -p -r <REV>
```

Remember that in Mercurial can refer to a local revision number, changeset, tag, a rangeset of revision numbers ... see the [manual page](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#log) for details and more options.